# How to debug a workflow?

Tags: 2007, workflow

[Please bear with me, I am NOT an SP Admin, and have very little experience with SP]

I have a workflow that has been running effectively for a couple of years - but in the last 2 weeks it's suddenly "stopped" intermittently.

Tasks get created most of the time, but occasionally the task is not created.

Please could someone advise on how to debug/investigate what is happening?

I have heard there is a "workflow history" but don't know how to find it.

I have also looked at the Lists running workflows and it shows a small increasing number of items each morning before the Users are in the office - so I think something somewhere is stuck?

Comment: I have found a "workflow history" list - but everything shows as UNID's and not sure how to translate back to a List/Task/Item?
Also, shows in there "Access Denied" a LOT of times?

Comment: Does ANYONE know how to investigate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue, where a workflow appeared not to start when a list item was modified. It was due to a previous instance of the workflow being suspended. Here's how to identify this situation:

Select the list item by ticking its checkbox
[image]

In the Items tab, click Workflows. The button is disabled if more than one was selected
[image]

Click the name of the **suspended** workflow (here, click OrderChanged)
[image]

Click the little blue icon to show the error message causing the stall
[image]

Finally, either **end** or **resume** the workflow